# anchor tag isn't working with show/hide

Tags: jquery, html

I want the hidden element (id="pres") to show up by jumping to that page area when a user clicks 'President [+]'. The problem is it won't jump to that area, but it shows the hidden element. Here is my HTML code:

```
<p><a id="Pres" href="#pres"> <b>President :</b> Name <span>[+]</span> </a></p>

<div id="pres">
<a href="images/pres.jpg" rel="lightbox[group101]" class="membersPhotosVer"><img src="images/pres.jpg"  /></a> <br/>
<p> bla bla bla </p>            
</div>
```

Jquery code:

```
$("#pres").hide();
$("#vp").hide();
$("#sec").hide();
$("#fin").hide();
$("#med").hide();
$("#ev").hide();
var pvsfme = $("#pres,#vp,#sec,#fin,#med,#ev");
var PVSFME = $("#Pres,#Vp,#Sec,#Fin,#Med,#Ev");

PVSFME.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var cli = $('#'+this.id.toLowerCase());
    cli.show();
    pvsfme.not(cli).hide();
    $(this).addClass("media-selected");
    PVSFME.not(this).removeClass("media-selected");
    $(this).children("span").text("[-]").show();
    PVSFME.not(this).children("span").text("[+]").show();
});
```

I'm wondering if anchor tag isn't working because of show/hide...or I'm missing something important.

Comment: You are preventing the default action

Comment: You might want to read about `e.preventDefault()`: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/. I'm wondering why you use it at all if you don't know what it does.

Comment: I actually need that prevent default so my fixed menu doesn't get screwed up when I click an anchor link. Is there another way to achieve this effect without/with anchor tags?

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove `e.preventDefault();`, otherwise default behavior for anchor element (navigation) will be cancelled.

Comment: I think that is intended. e.preventDefault will stop it from opening up images/pres.jpg, not interrupt the js. **edit** after re-reading the question, maybe you're right.

Comment: @peterchon: I believe the OP is talking about clicking on the first link, not the link that already is inside the target element. In fact, the event handler is not bound to the link you are talking about.

Comment: Yea I meant clicking the link that will show the hidden element...i want it to jump to the hidden element after that click since sometimes the user can't see it if the previous element was too long

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're just looking to insert:

```
<a name="pres"></a>
```

At the top of your `#pres` div.

Comment: Not necessary, the `id` attribute has the same functionality. Even if that anchor was there, it would solve the problem.